# css icon position not work on mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, mozilla

icon position work's fine on chrome. but on mozzilla, the icon move from the position. the question is, how to implement this code to mozilla firefox? is there a difference for chrome or mozzilla? The css code is below

```css
.searchbar-1{
          
          float: right;
          width: 300px;
          vertical-align: middle;
          white-space: nowrap;
          position: relative;
          margin-right: 120px;
          margin-top: -4px;
        }
        .searchbar-1 input#search{
          width: 300px;
          height: 40px;
          background: #E6E7E9;
          border: none;
          font-size: 10pt;
          font-style: italic;
          float: left;
          color: #63717f;
          padding-left: 45px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .searchbar-1 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
           color: #65737e;
        }
         
        
         
        .searchbar-1 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder {  
           color: #65737e;  
        }
        
        .searchbar-1 .icon{
          position: absolute;
          top: 0%;
          margin-left: 12px;
          margin-top: 9px;
          z-index: 1;
          color: black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchbar-1">
                <span class="icon"><i class="material-icons" (click)="applyFilterCustom(search)">search</i></span>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" id="search" placeholder="Where would you like to go next?" name="search" (keyup.enter)="applyFilterCustom(search)" />
    </div>
```

Comment: You do not specify `left` or `right` for your icon, so browser tries to guess where to place it. Add `.icon {left: 0; top: 0}` to fix issue

Comment: @Justinas but on google chrome thats works fine

Comment: So it guessed correctly, but you still rely on browser default behavior

Comment: thanks. you right. chrome and firefox have different behaviour.

Comment: Please explain why the "mozilla" tag is better than "firefox". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use `position: absolute;` you must have to define position. in your case you have defined the `top` position but not `left` or `right` so based on your requirement you have to define any of them. which will resolve your issue for browser.